# How I can add new file to my .run archive?(makeself)

Tags: linux

I have ".run" archive and I want to add some file in it.

The documentation says([makeself](https://makeself.io/)):

> --append (new in 2.1.x): Append data to an existing archive, instead of creating a new one. In this mode, the settings from the original
> archive are reused (compression type, label, embedded script), and
> thus don’t need to be specified again on the command line.

But I still don't know what to do.

This is my attempt:

```
[root@localhost 10:28 result] # /opt/makeself-2.4.5/makeself.sh --append my_test_app.run my_new_file 
Directory assistant-4.8.run does not exist.
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this today so ran into your post and was able to find a way.
Basically, you don't add individual files, but files inside specified directory. Example is as follows:

jezekilj@JezekiljDesktop:~/Documents/PySave/Easy-Vino-VNC$ makeself --append ./add/ ./vino-autoinstaller
Header is 586 lines long

About to compress 8 KB of data...
Adding files to archive named "./vino-autoinstaller"...
./
./org.gnome.desktop.remote-access.txt
CRC: 1102495668
MD5: df6e87068846390fd0066cdd7c1dd8e8
Self-extractable archive "./vino-autoinstaller" successfully updated.

so my installer is named vino-autoinstaller and it is in the directory where Terminal was opened.
In sub-directory named 'add' I placed one file and it was added to original auto-installer for Vino Server. If more files had been there they would have all been added.